# extracting contents from a tag "extract" from Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having a corpus in xml in which one of the tags is named extract `<EXTRACT>`. but the term is a keyword in Beautifulsoup. How can I extract the contents of this tag. when i write `entry.extract.text` it returns error and when I use `entry.extract`, the entire contents are extracted.

from what I know about Beautifulsoup, it performs case folding of tags. If there is some method to overcome this,it also might be helpful to me.

NB:
for the time being I resolved the issue with following method.

```
extra = entry.find('extract')
absts.write(str(extra.text))
```

But I would like to know if there is any way to use it as we use with other tags like `entry.tagName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to BS source code `tag.tagname` actually calls `tag.find("tagname")` under the hood. Here's how `__getattr__()` method of a `Tag` class looks:

```
def __getattr__(self, tag):
    if len(tag) > 3 and tag.endswith('Tag'):
        # BS3: soup.aTag -> "soup.find("a")
        tag_name = tag[:-3]
        warnings.warn(
            '.%sTag is deprecated, use .find("%s") instead.' % (
                tag_name, tag_name))
        return self.find(tag_name)
    # We special case contents to avoid recursion.
    elif not tag.startswith("__") and not tag=="contents":
        return self.find(tag)
    raise AttributeError(
        "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__, tag))
```

See that it is completely based on `find()`, so it's pretty much ok to use `tag.find("extract")` in your case:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """<test><EXTRACT>extract text</EXTRACT></test>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
test = soup.find('test')
print test.find("extract").text  # prints 'extract text'
```

Also, you can use `test.extractTag.text`, but it is deprecated and I wouldn't recommend it.

Hope that helps.